# Shrinking spacing around definition environment

Tags: spacing

I would like to decrease the space before and after a definition by 1pt. Can anyone tell me how to appropriately tweak the environment? Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example we can use as foundation for working with your setup? For example, how do you define your definition? Your minimal example should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Maybe `\vspace{-1pt}` before and after the environment.

Comment: There's more than one way to create an environment called `definition`. We need to know how you go about creating this environment.